# Is there a good design pattern: common method has a superclass param but contains calls to methods available in child classes (thus requiring casting)

Tags: java, generics, casting, polymorphism, parametric-polymorphism

So if I wanted a method to be common for 3 child classes, like this:

```
public void commonForAllAnimals(Animal animal) {
  // this method exists in subclasses that I need
  animal.foo();
  // only in Dog
  animal.woof();
  // only in Cat
  animal.meow();
}
```

what is the best way to go about it? I tried casting but I still end up with code duplication. Is there a simple way to at least call the 'foo()' method which would the incoming child objects have defined?

Comment: Can't you call woof() or meow() in the foo()s methods in Dog and Cat ?

Comment: @Julien FYI: I updated the question slightly! I don't understand your question? `foo()` is a method that is common to child classes that are going to be passed when using this method (other child classes might not have it)

Comment: I imagine that foo() is defined abstract in Animal and implemented in the sub-classes. The meaning of my question is : as foo() is redefined in the subclasses Dog and Cat and in your method commonForAllAnimals you need to call woof() or meow() accordingly after calling foo() why don't you call woof() or meow() at the end of the method foo() in respectively Dog and Cat ?

Answer (score 1):

What you need to do is :

1- call foo

2- make an animal "talk"

To do that you can consider such an implementation

```
abstract class Animal {
  abstract void foo(); // pure abstract
  abstract void talk(); // pure abstract too
  public void commonForAllAnimals(Animal animal) {
    // this method exists in subclasses that I need
    animal.foo();
    // make any sub-Animal talk
    animal.talk();
  }
}

class Dog extends Animal {
  @override
  void foo() {
    // make the Dog's foo
  }
  @override
  void talk() {
    this.woof();
  }
  void woof() {
    // make a woof
  }
}

class Cat extends Animal {
  @override
  void foo() {
    // make the Cat's foo
  }
  @override
  void talk() {
    this.meow();
  }
  void meow() {
    // make a meow
  }
}
```

Every Animal sub-class has to implement the talk() method and considering the implementation into the sub-class it will do a woof() or a meow(). No cast needed, you just use class hierarchy.